# Inverse of State-space representation (control)

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Ask two questions from a paper (2012 ACC):

Consider the plant:

[image]

Let X be the stabilizing solution of the Riccati equation:

[image]

where [image].
Define the LQR gain by [image].

The transfer matrix [image] has a **left spectral factorization** [image],
where WL is given by

[image]

Questions:

1. If I know the $W_L$, how to derive the $W_L^{-1}$, (bottom one)
2. (Basic question) Why does the Riccati equation is $(A, B_2, C_1)$ not $(A, B_1, C_1)$ or
   $(A, B_2, C_2)$?

Comment: Multiplying $W_L W_L^{-1}$ doesn't seem to yield the identity matrix, unless we know stuff about the matrices $A, B_2, K$. Can you provide more context?

Comment: I think the representation is not really a matrix; it is like   C*inv(sI-A)B + D

Comment: What is $X$? I believe it is a solution to some matrix equation.

Comment: More complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question is about inverting a state space system that represents the dynamics from $u$ to $y$ such that the representation is from $y$ to $u$.

If you write down the equations explicitly:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot x &= Ax+Bu\\
y &= Cx+Du
\end{align}
$$
Now assuming $D$ is invertible, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\dot x &= Ax+B(-D^{-1}Cx + D^{-1}y)\\
u &= -D^{-1}Cx + D^{-1}y
\end{align}
$$
So the state space from $y$ to $u$ is given by the realization
$$
G^{-1}(s) = \begin{bmatrix}A-BD^{-1}C &BD^{-1}\\-CD^{-1}&D^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then you can see the similarity between this inverse and $W_L$.

For the second question, in Linear Quadratic Cost function you would like to add the cost of the input to your cost function. In this formulation, often $B_1$ is the disturbance input to the system and $B_2$ models the input matrix.

Hence you want the second input appearing on the performance channel.

Comment: Great answer! What would be the inverse if D = 0 though?