# The inverse of a state space matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

First of all, I would like to link this question to another one about the inverse of a state space representation:

[Inverse of State-space representation (control)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897927/inverse-of-state-space-representation)

I understand the prove as given on the previous page, but I want to prove it another way. I want to show that $G(s)G^{-1}(s)=I$. However, I get stuck when trying to prove this:

When G(s) is given as: $G(s) = \begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$

Then the inverse is given as:
$G^{-1}(s) = \begin{bmatrix}A-BD^{-1}C &BD^{-1}\\-D^{-1}C&D^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$

From these state space representations, we get:

$G(s)G^{-1}(s) = [C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D][-D^{-1}C(sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD{-1}+D^{-1}]$

$= -C(sI-A)^{-1}BD^{-1}C(sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1}  + C(sI-A)^{-1}BD^{-1} + C(sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}BD^{-1} + I  $

Here is where I get stuck. Since $DD^{-1}=I$, the rest should equal the zero matrix, but I fail to prove this.

Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You have the sign of a term wrong. Other than that you can write
$$-C(sI-A)^{-1}BD^{-1}C(sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}  + C(sI-A)^{-1} - C(sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}=\left[-C(sI-A)^{-1}BD^{-1}C+C(sI-A)^{-1}(sI-A+BD^{-1}C)-C\right](sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}=\left[-C(sI-A)^{-1}BD^{-1}C+C(sI-A)^{-1}(sI-A)+C(sI-A)^{-1}BD^{-1}C-C\right](sI-A+BD^{-1}C)^{-1}=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow. It was actually relatively easy. Just I had to come up with some multiplication myself.

I have one remaining question. What happens when the D-matrix is zero? Most practical systems happen to have a D-matrix with zero right? If I am not wrong all proper systems have a D-matrix equal to zero.

The frequency domain representation has always an inverse? Am I wrong? Just make the denominator numerator and vice versa.

What does it mean for practical systems that the D-matrix is zero and why would they not be invertible? Can you give me some feeling?

Comment: @user137632 When $D=0$ then the transfer function is strictly proper. This means that the nominator of the inverse is of higher order than its denominator. This cannot be implemented physically, only approximately.