# Get zero, poles and gain from state space model?

Tags: matrices, transformation, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I'm going to transform a state space model:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu \\ y = Cx + Du$$

Into a transfer function:
$$G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}$$

What I need is to find the zeros, poles and gain. Finding poles are really easy. I just find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

$$det(sI-A) = 0$$

Then I get the poles $$s_i = a\Re_i + b\Im_i$$

But how about the gain and zeros? How do I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static gain is simply $C(- A)^{-1}B+D$ directly from the transfer function definition. To compute zeros, it is more involved as it depends on your definition of a zero (invariant or transfer?).

There are some references in MATLABs help https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tzero.html

Comment: Ok! So the gain is when s -> 0. Smart. Now it's only the zeros left.

Comment: Do you think that the zeros can be described as $$Ct_iq_i^HB$$ where $t_i$ is the left eigenvector and $q_i$ is the right eigenvector and $H$ is the conjugate transpose?

Comment: When $s=0$ one would be left with the gain times the product of all zeros divided by the product of all poles (at least for the SISO case). So this expression seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I was trying that. Let's say that I have state space model A= [-0.75 -0.5; 1 0], B = [1; 0], C = [0.5 0.25], D = 0. Eigenvalues of A are -0.37500 + 0.59948i, -0.37500 - 0.59948i and the left eigenvectors are $$\begin{bmatrix}
-0.30619 + 0.48947i & -0.30619 - 0.48947i \\
   0.81650 + 0.00000i  & 0.81650 - 0.00000i
\end{bmatrix}$$ and left eigenvectors are $$\begin{bmatrix}
0.81650 + 0.00000i &   0.81650 - 0.00000i \\
   0.30619 - 0.48947i &  0.30619 + 0.48947i
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen that means >> C*t(1)*ctranspose(q(1))*B
ans = -0.12500 + 0.19983i will not give me a zero? Right? Look at this http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_Conversions I'm expecting -0.5 as zero.

Comment: Sorry! I was reading "correct" insted of incorrect. I found that formula from Sigurd Skogestad's book "Multivariable control".

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Matlab get an other static gain by using MATLAB's tpkdata command.

Comment: Huh? There is no such command

Comment: How to compute the gain when there is an integrator (A not invertible) ?

Comment: then the gain would be infinite

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard problem of finding the transfer function from a state-space model of a linear system. In particular, $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu \implies X(s)=(sI-A)^{-1}B U(s)$, and $y=Cx+Du \implies Y(s)=CX(s)+DU(s)$. Consequently,
$$Y(s) = CX(s) + D U(s) = (C(sI-A)^{-1}B +D)U(s) \implies G(s) = C(sI-A)^{-1}B +D.$$
Once you have $G(s)$, you can compute the poles, zeros etc. of the transfer function.

Comment: Thank you. But compute $C(sI-A)^{-1}B + D$ requries symbolic use? Or should I first compute all poles $s_i$ then compute  $C(s_iI-A)^{-1}B + D$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Maybe, you are talking about finding the transfer function in MATLAB. Check the following link for the available MATLAB functions. https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/functionlist.html

Comment: Yes! I trying to find the transferfunction from a state space model. But I have a problem with to find the zeros.

Comment: I don't have MATLAB.

Comment: You just need to compute $(sI-A)^{-1}$, which will be a matrix whose elements would be functions of $s$. After that computing $G(s)$ should be easy. As an example, if $A$ is an identity matrix of size $2$ then $(sI-A)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1/(s-1) & 0 \\ 0 & 1/(s-1)\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Yes. I know, but then I need to build a laplace library. I need to do this numericaly.

Comment: Sorry! Forget about the laplace library. I was thinking on the state transition matrix.

Comment: But can anyone explain WHY the poles are $(sI - A)^{-1}$? The full equation for $G(s)$ has this as the denominator of the first term, but also has a second term, $D$. Strictly speaking what happens to the $D$ when we calculate the poles? Do we just ignore this term and assume it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

The zeros can be computed by

$$(z\begin{bmatrix}
I &0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ 
C & D
\end{bmatrix}) = 0$$

MATLAB / Octave command:

```
>> zero = qz(A, B)
```

Which computes the generalized eigenvalues lambda of (sB-A)

Comment: This only works when the transfer function matrix is square (same number of inputs as outputs), because the generalized eigenvalue problem requires a square matrix.

Comment: It can also be noted that if $D$ is invertable the [transfer function is invertable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897927) as well. The zeros can also be found by solving for the eigenvalues of $A-B\,D^{-1}C$.

Comment: @Kwinvanderveen  most of the time, D = 0 and then they poles will be exactly as the zeros?

Comment: @Kwinvanderveen  you can change the rows and the colums of C,D and B matrix so you only do a SISO TF, even if it's a MIMO, MISO, SIMO. Then you don't need to worry about if it a square or not. I have tested it.

Comment: No, if $D=0$ then $D^{-1}=\infty$. However I looked at this case and then it would also be possible to find the zeros by finding the eigenvalues of $A-B\,(C\,B)^{-1}C\,A$. This this will always put one of the zeros at zero, which should be ignored.